# "Unknown issue with Google Play Services" on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I am trying to update my Android app (which needs SDK support from version 7 up) to the new Google Maps Android API v2.

I've currently tried to use [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map) and many tutorials like [this one](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-supportmapfragment.html).

However, when I navigate to the map view, I get a blank screen with the following message: "Unknown issue with Google Play Services" with no explicit error or warning messages in LogCat.

**Things I've Tried**

- My device has the most recent version of Google Play
- I'm using SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment
- all the required permissions are in the manifest
- the Maps API library is added to the project
- Eclipse and the SDK are up to date
- the message still shows when I export my app with a keystore that's linked with a Google Maps Android API key on the Google API console.

**My goal** is to have the map view display in a tab window on a FragmentActivity where I am using a TabHost but this problem still exists with [the tutorial code](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-supportmapfragment.html).

Below is the log information when running the activity with the SupportMapFragment:

```
05-22 11:32:53.219: I/dalvikvm(6578): Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onAttach, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onAttach
05-22 11:32:53.219: W/dalvikvm(6578): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 730: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.onAttach (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
05-22 11:32:53.219: D/dalvikvm(6578): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
05-22 11:32:53.219: D/dalvikvm(6578): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0008 in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;.onAttach (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
05-22 11:32:53.219: I/dalvikvm(6578): Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate
05-22 11:32:53.219: W/dalvikvm(6578): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 744: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.onInflate (Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
05-22 11:32:53.219: D/dalvikvm(6578): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
05-22 11:32:53.219: D/dalvikvm(6578): VFY: dead code 0x0003-001b in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;.onInflate (Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
```

Something tells me that's going to be important. ;) I look forward to any ideas or suggestions. Thank you all!

Comment: have added the support library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote on Google Maps API V2 integration, go over all the 9 steps and make sure you do all of them correctly:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: You were absolutely right! My version of ActionBarSherlock was out of date so I had an outdated support library. Following your steps fixed it. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with the support library. (android-support-v4.jar)

1. Download the latest Android Support package.
2. Copy /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar to your projects libs folder.
3. Update your manifest file and set the target API level to the latest release!
4. Import the Fragment class and related APIs from the android.support.v4.app package.